# 0.1 is an approximation, but why not round up behind the scenes as well when we add 0.1 and 0.2?

Tags: floating-point, usability

I get that `0.1` is actually `0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...`.

However, in Python for example, why output `0.30000000000000004` to the prompt when we add 0.1 and 0.2?

Why not just keep up the illusion and give the user the blue pill and tell him 0.1+0.2 is 0.3? Ignorance is bliss, isn't it?

Comment: Not a python expert, but I'm pretty sure there exists a python function for string format, right? `print ("{:.1f}".format(0.1 + 0.2))` prints `0.3`

Comment: In general, you should decide how many significant digits or decimal places make sense in your application. It will usually be a lot less than 16. Format output accordingly.

Comment: "Why not just keep up the illusion" --> Speed/Accuracy.  It would take more code/time to round to "nice" decimal-like numbers than to round to nearest.

Answer (score 4):

The Python specification is not strict about floating-point behavior, but many implementations use the IEEE-754 binary64 format. Of the numbers representable in this format, the one closest to .1 is:

```
.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110102,
```

and the one closest to .2 is:

```
.001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101002.
```

The real-number sum of these is:

```
.010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011102.
```

That number has 54 significant digits. (56 digits are shown, for alignment and comparison to previous numbers. The leading 0 is just for alignment, and the trailing 0 has no significance to the value, so there are 54 digits from the first 1 to the last 1.) The binary64 format has just 53 digits for the significand (the fraction portion of the representation). So this number cannot be represented in the binary64 format.

It is exactly midway between two representable numbers:

```
.010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011002 and
.010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100002.
```

When there is a tie, the common rule for breaking the tie is to use the number with the even digit in the low position. Since the first ends with 0111 in the bits that fit in the significand and the second ends with 1000, the second is chosen, and that is the result of adding those two numbers using floating-point addition.

That value is 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

Keep in mind that the part of the computer or software doing the addition has no knowledge that these numbers originally came from .1 or .2. It just has the bits shown above to work with. It gets a sum that is midway between two representable values and has to choose one as the result. The rule for that choice is to use the value with the even low digit.

Once that result is obtained, there is a choice about how to format it. Again, the Python specification is not strict, but one formatting behavior is to show just enough digits to uniquely distinguish the number from neighboring representable values. The representable number nearest .3 is 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875 and so, when displaying that number, “.3” would be shown. When displaying 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125, we cannot use “.3”, because that fails to distinguish it from 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. So, to distinguish it, it must be displayed as “0.30000000000000004”.

Another common formatting method is to convert a number to decimal using a fixed number of decimal digits, say 17, and then to remove trailing zeros. In this case, that would have the same results, “.3” for 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, and “0.30000000000000004” for 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

Additionally, it is not a good idea to hide information from programmers. Doing so allows mistaken ideas to grow and bugs to occur. When values are not exactly what a naïve interpretation might think them to be, it is better to show the differences rather than conceal them.